Does some knot group fail to surject onto any alternating group?
Are there known examples of knot groups that do not surject onto any alternating group? I would be a little surprised if the answer is negative.
Update: To reflect the interesting part of the question, I'd prefer to avoid the unknot and the "abelianization" in the obvious way. So, the target alternating group should be considered as $A_n$ $(n > 3)$. That is, as suggested by YCor, does there exist some nonabelian knot group $G$ such that for every $n > 3$, the alternating group $A_n$ is not a quotient of $G$?

Since the meaning of "any" might be ambiguous, the question is, if I'm correct: does there exist some know group $G$ such that for every $n\ge 3$, the alternating group $\mathrm{Alt}_n$ is not a quotient of $G$. Right?

The heuristic model of Dunfield-Thurston suggests that the probability a fundamental group of "random" $3$-manfold surjects onto $A_n$ tends to a (positive) limiting probability as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502567), so it seems exceedingly unlikely for hyperbolic knots. OTOH Torus knots have fundamental group $\langle x,y |x^p=y^q \rangle$ and I suspect it should be elementary to prove that this group has many alternating quotients outside the degenerate cases.

Re: the previous comment: it's not hard to show a $p$-cycle and a $q$-cycle (where $p<q$ are both odd) generate $A_q$.

@YCor There might be some misunderstandings when I said “abelianization” I was referring to the exclusion of the unknot. Similar to the nontrivial knot…I’ll use the phrase “unknot” then.

Probably you should say "non-abelian knot group", because "nontrivial group" usually means not reduced to the unit.

The unknot and the hopf link have abelian knot groups.  See here.  Hence  they can't surject onto an $A_n$ for $n\gt3.$

:D Of course this doesn’t really answer the interesting version of the question.
